# is there a way to tell npm to ignore react?

Tags: npm

I have an angular app, and apparently dependencies in my package have react in them, and when I try to `npm i` I get a whole lot of a output about react garbage not being compatible, but I am not even using react, so I don't care..  Is there a way to put in my package file something that will tell npm to ignore react completely?

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-inspector@5.1.1
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@">= 16.8.6" from @design-systems/utils@2.12.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@design-systems/utils
npm WARN     @design-systems/utils@"2.12.0" from @devtools-ds/themes@1.2.0
npm WARN     node_modules/@devtools-ds/themes
npm WARN   33 more (@devtools-ds/object-inspector, @devtools-ds/themes, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.8.4 || ^17.0.0" from react-inspector@5.1.1
npm WARN node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/node_modules/react-inspector
npm WARN   react-inspector@"^5.1.0" from @storybook/addon-actions@6.5.13
npm WARN   node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.8.4 || ^17.0.0" from react-inspector@5.1.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/node_modules/react-inspector
npm WARN     react-inspector@"^5.1.0" from @storybook/addon-actions@6.5.13
npm WARN     node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @mdx-js/react@1.6.22
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@">= 16.8.6" from @design-systems/utils@2.12.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@design-systems/utils
npm WARN     @design-systems/utils@"2.12.0" from @devtools-ds/themes@1.2.0
npm WARN     node_modules/@devtools-ds/themes
npm WARN   33 more (@devtools-ds/object-inspector, @devtools-ds/themes, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.13.1 || ^17.0.0" from @mdx-js/react@1.6.22
npm WARN node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/node_modules/@mdx-js/react
npm WARN   @mdx-js/react@"^1.6.22" from @storybook/addon-docs@6.5.13
npm WARN   node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.13.1 || ^17.0.0" from @mdx-js/react@1.6.22
npm WARN   node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/node_modules/@mdx-js/react
npm WARN     @mdx-js/react@"^1.6.22" from @storybook/addon-docs@6.5.13
npm WARN     node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-dom@17.0.2
npm WARN Found: react@16.14.0
```